# Call to undefined function in Laravel view

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.5

I have a `About Us` portion in my Laravel website home page. I have uploaded a huge article for `About Us` from admin panel which is shown in `about us` page. But I want to show a specific number of word for `about us` in home page and add `read more` after that. while click on `read more` it goes to `about us` page.

But I can't show specific number of words from that article in my home page.

I have use `echo word_teaser_end($about_us[0]->details, 10);` function but it gives error

`Call to undefined function word_teaser_end() (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\OFFICE\SEN_CARE\sencare.com.bd\resources\views\frontend\home\home.blade.php)`

What should I do now ?

Comment: Clearly the function is not defined. Where did you define it, if anywhere?

Comment: check str_limit($about_us[0]->details,'10')

Comment: Search for function `word_teaser_end` in code. Is this defined anywhere?

Comment: @Lovepreet Singh.....I have used this function in my laravel blade template.

Comment: The question wasn't where you used it but where you defined it.

Comment: @ArafatRahman, anywhere else in code?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh...no where else in code

Comment: So you should remove the use of this function. Define your own function if you want some specific functionality.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh...it's a PHP function...And I have already add `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",` in `composer.json` file. Also add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` inside `config/app.php`

Comment: @LovepreetSingh...I have no other specific functionality of my own. Give me any suggession please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the `word_teaser_end()` as it's define function,
Try `str_limit()` helper function which can help you to load the number of words from string

```
{{ str_limit($string,'10') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-limit

Comment: It works....but show the tagline too... suppose i have a html part `<center>Testing purpose</center>` in the `$string` object...while I use {{ str_limit($string,'10') }}.
It will show `<center>Te`....that means with tag it counts

Comment: {!! str_limit($string,'10') !!} add something like this

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
{!! str_limit($string,'10') !!}
```